# Почему буквы Е, Ё, Ю и Я, содержащие согласный звук [й], называют гласными? Правильно ли вообще называть буквы гласными или согласными?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, фонетика

Буквы Е, Ё, Ю и Я могут, в зависимости от положения в слове, обозначать один или два звука.

Они либо обозначают два звука: [йэ], [йо], [йу], [йа] — [согласный звук + гласный звук], либо смягчают предыдущий согласный звук и тогда обозначают один звук.

Несмотря на то, что эти буквы обозначают [согласный звук + гласный звук] их относят именно к гласным.

На каком основании?

Что вообще означают прилагательные «гласный» и «согласный»?

Согласно Малому академическому словарю под редакцией А. П. Евгеньевой:

> **гла́сный**, -ая, -ое. Образуемый при свободном прохождении воздуха через
> полость рта (о звуках речи).
>
> **согла́сный**, -ая, -ое. Лингв. Образуемый при прохождении сильной струи
> воздуха через преграду в каком-л. месте речевого аппарата (о звуках
> речи).

Звук [й] считается согласным, поскольку образуется при прохождении струи воздуха через преграду.

Но ведь и при произнесении звуков, обозначаемых буквами Е, Ё, Ю и Я воздух точно также преодолевает преграду, поскольку первым звуком идёт [й]: [йэ], [йо], [йу] и [йа].

А раз при произнесении струя воздуха проходит через преграду, то буквы Е, Ё, Ю и Я — согласные.

Что такое согласная и гласная буквы?

В толковом словаре Ушакова:

> **гла́сный**…
> 1. О буквах: изображающая на письме гласный звук.
>
> **согла́сный**…
> 3. в знач. сущ. согла́сная, ой, ж. (грам.). Буква, обозначающая такой звук.

Значит: гласная буква — это буква, обозначающая на письме гласный звук, а согласная буква — это буква, обозначающая на письме согласный звук.

Какой звук, согласный или гласный обозначают буквы: Е [йэ], Ё [йо], Ю [йу] и Я [йа]?

И тот и другой! Таким образом, их нельзя отнести ни к гласным, ни к согласным.

А может быть вообще не правильно называть буквы гласными или согласными? А гласными и согласными могут быть только звуки?

Ведь буквы — это всего лишь графические обозначения звуков на письме и они пишутся, а не произносятся. Звучание же имеют звуки речи и именно они могут быть гласными или согласными, на не буквы.

---

Учителя относя буквы Е, Ё, Ю и Я к гласным, аргументируют это тем, что их можно пропеть.

И они их поют: Е [йэээээ…], Ё [йооооо…], Ю [йууууу…] и Я [йааааа…].

Но проблема в том, что сначала во рту образуется препятствие для произнесения звука [й], а только потом уже идёт звук, который можно тянуть.

С таким же успехом можно пропеть буквы, которые относят к согласным: Б [бэээээ…], В [вэээээ…], Г [гэээээ…] и так далее.

---

Мои вопросы:

1. Почему звук [й] относят к согласным, а буквы его содержащие: Е [йэ], Ё [йо], Ю [йу] и Я [йа] — к гласным.
2. Правильно ли вообще называть буквы гласными или согласными, или всё-таки гласными и согласными могут быть только звуки, а не графические знаки, которые используются для их обозначения.